# Transform dict recursively

Tags: python, recursion

Example dict :

```
simple_dict = {
    'root 1': [
        'root 1 1',
        'root 1 2'
    ],
    'root 2': [
        'root 2 1',
        'root 2 2',
        {'root 2 3': [
            'root 2 3 1',
            'root 2 3 2'
        ]},
        'root 2 4',
    ],
    'root 3': ['root 3 1']
}
```

I'm trying to transform it to this :

```
root_dict = [
    {
        'name': 'root1',
        'children': [
            {
                'name': 'root 1 1'
            },
            {
                'name': 'root 1 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'root 2',
        'children': [
            {
                'name': 'root 2 1'
            },
            {
                'name': 'root 2 2'
            },
            {
                'name': 'root 2 3',
                'children': [
                    {
                        'name': 'root 2 3 1'
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'root 2 3 2'
                    }

                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'root 2 4'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'root 3',
        'children': [
            {
                'name': 'root 3 1'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

all i got is wrote a function that recursively traverses the dictionary, but it loses the third level of nesting:

```
def dict_to_tree_options(tree):
    options = []
    for key, value in tree.items():
        elem = {
            'name': f'{key}',
            'children': []
        }
        #print(key, value)
        for i in value:
            if isinstance(i, dict):
                #print('deeper')
                outer_elem = {
                    'name': f'{i}'
                }
                dict_to_tree_options(i)
            else:
                inner_elem = {
                    'name': f'{i}'
                }
                elem['children'].append(inner_elem)
                #print(key, i, '\n')    
        options.append(elem)
    print(options)
```

```
[{'name': 'root 2 3', 'children': [{'name': 'root 2 3 1'}, {'name': 'root 2 3 2'}]}]
[{'name': 'root 1', 'children': [{'name': 'root 1 1'}, {'name': 'root 1 2'}]}, {'name': 'root 2', 'children': [{'name': 'root 2 1'}, {'name': 'root 2 2'}, {'name': 'root 2 4'}]}, {'name': 'root 3', 'children': [{'name': 'root 3 1'}]}]
```

apparently, I don't understand how a recursive function should work, because it seems to me that every time the recursion is called, the options variable is redefined and I don't understand what happens to it next

Comment: The second structure looks like even more of an abomination than the first. What's the goal here? And yes, since your first line is `options = []` it's going to get recreated every call. Did you mean to pass it in?

Comment: I need to convert the first dictionary to the format of the second one because the system I use accepts it only in this form. Look at the second row of output, it almost what i need but it loos 3rd lever of root, please help me i need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it. When doing a recursive function always think of your stopping conditions first !

```py
def format_dict(entry):
    if not isinstance(entry, (list, dict)):
        return {'name': entry}
    
    if isinstance(entry, list):
        return [format_dict(e) for e in entry]
    
    if isinstance(entry, dict):
        children = [{
            'name': key, 'children': format_dict(value) 
        } for key, value in entry.items()]
        
        if len(children) == 1:
            return children[0]
        
        return children
```

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful working solution, but i got ```None``` if value contains integer, can you fix it please?

Comment: Done, just replace the `if isinstance(entry, str)` with `if not isinstance(entry, (list, dict))`

Comment: Yes it is, i just added ```return {'name': str(entry)}```, thank you so much! :3

Answer (score 2):

Here's the implementation that does what you requested:

```
def transform(value):
    if not isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
        return {'name': value}

    if isinstance(value, list):
        return [transform(item) for item in value]

    return [{'name': key, 'children': transform(value_)} for key, value_ in value.items()]
```

Comment: Almost works, but there is a small problem: ```[{'name': 'root 2 3',
     'children': [{'name': 'root 2 3 1'}, {'name': 'root 2 3 2'}]}]``` this part is wrapped in a list but should not be

Comment: The code results in the desired output you wanted, you can't keep it only as a dict, since `name` in not unique....

Answer (score 0):

You could try to return the options array. Then when the elem is a dict you should append the {name: f'{I}', children: dict_to_tree_options(I)} to the children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a list comprehension:

```
def to_tree(d):
   if not isinstance(d, dict):
      return {'name':d}
   return [{'name':a, 'children':list(map(to_tree, b))} for a, b in d.items()]
```

---

```
import json
simple_dict = {'root 1': ['root 1 1', 'root 1 2'], 'root 2': ['root 2 1', 'root 2 2', {'root 2 3': ['root 2 3 1', 'root 2 3 2']}, 'root 2 4'], 'root 3': ['root 3 1']} 
print(json.dumps(to_tree(simple_dict), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
   {
      "name": "root 1",
      "children": [
          {
             "name": "root 1 1"
          },
          {
             "name": "root 1 2"
          }
       ]
   },
   {
      "name": "root 2",
      "children": [
         {
            "name": "root 2 1"
         },
         {
            "name": "root 2 2"
         },
         [
             {
                 "name": "root 2 3",
                 "children": [
                     {
                        "name": "root 2 3 1"
                     },
                     { 
                        "name": "root 2 3 2"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ],
          {
              "name": "root 2 4"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
     "name": "root 3",
     "children": [
          {
            "name": "root 3 1"
          }
       ]
    }
]
```